# Analytic Integration Bug of Hypergeometric function in Version 11.3?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I got this integral

```
Integrate[ q^(-4 + d) (-1 + Hypergeometric0F1[d/2, -(1/4) q^2 x^2]), 
    {q, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 2 < d < 3]
```

and in 11.0.1 (EDIT: 11.0.0, 11.1 and 11.2 also checked out) mma gives

$$\frac{\Gamma (d-1) \left| x\right| ^{3-d}}{d-3}$$
but in 11.3 mma can't give a result.

Is this a bug introduced after 11.0.1 or what 11.0.1 gives is in fact wrong?

Comment: The result in 11.0.1 seems to be correct in view of calculations for $d=2.5,x=2.$

Comment: I got an equvalent result (-2 + d) Abs[x]^(3 - d) Gamma[-3 + d] from versions 7.0 and 10.2, versions 11.3 and 11.0.0.0. without any result.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Did you add those conditions I listed? Those are essential in my evaluation.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec I did the evaluation on another machine with mma 11.0.0 and got the same result as 11.0.1.

Comment: @Turgon: Copy/paste your code, with Assumptions, of course.

Comment: This will give a result. `Integrate[
 q^(-4 + d) (-1 + Hypergeometric0F1[d/2, -(1/4) q^2 x^2]), {q, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 2 < d < 3, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]`. It is not immediately obvious to me what changed causes it to be unevaluated without that option setting.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your reply! I imagine it'd mean for my given condition, mma 11.3 won't give a result, but in some unknown region it can? And mma itself can't figure it out?

Comment: In this case I don't think it is region/assumptions dependent. My suspicion is that a method may have been disabled except for the case of `GenerateConditions->False`, and the method otherwise used might be timing out while taking a limit.